# Editing cn1-ckeditor lib in eclipse

Tags: codenameone

I would like to edit this [cn1lib](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-ckeditor).

Once I have cloned the project in Eclipse, how do I update the cn1lib file to use it in my own project ?

[EDIT]: I cloned CodenameOne project and tried to build it using the ant build.xml file but then i got the following errors:

> [javac] Compiling 505 source files to path\workspace\CodenameOne\CodenameOne\build\classes
>       [javac] Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   path\workspace\CodenameOne\CodenameOne\nbproject\build-impl.xml:938: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   path\workspace\CodenameOne\CodenameOne\nbproject\build-impl.xml:270: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

I also get some package dependencies error when I try to build the cn1lib project.

What am I doing wrong ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit [this file](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-ckeditor/blob/master/nbproject/project.properties), notice it includes many local paths which get automatically flagged in NetBeans if you open the project but Eclipse is oblivious to them.

E.g. `/Volumes/Windows VMS/NetbeansProjects/CodenameOneJS/build/classes` might be problematic but also `lib/CLDC11.jar` etc. would be a problem. You can just copy the lib directory from a regular Codename One project to fix the latter.

Comment: I resolved dependencies using my own project's path and codenameOne project path.
I also replaced the ckeditor's lib folder with my project's lib folder.
I removed the following line from the build.xml file:
`<ant dir="../CKeditorDemo/" target="refresh-libs" inheritall="false"/>`

I could build cn1-ckeditor in netbeans without any errors but in eclipse the build succeeds with a javadoc building error. I don't think that's an issue.

It also creates the .cn1lib zip in the dist folder but when I use it in my project my changes won't be handled.

Thank you for all your assistance

Comment: You need a jar from the netbeans library root that will solve the javadoc error. It generates the stubs for the lib so it's very necessary.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what jar you're talking about: I already  have imported both CLDC11.jar and CodenameOne.jar. I also have generated the cn1lib file with netbeans and could make it work in a netbeans project. But when I put this file in my eclipse project my changes won't show up. Eclipse will show the methods I have added and won't complain when I use them but then it show a compile error. I really would like to make it work in eclipse.

Comment: You should have `Stubber.jar` which should be in the root of a cn1lib created from NetBeans or IDEA. The cn1lib is a zip file, unzip it and look within the one generated from NetBeans and the one generated by eclipse and let me know what's the difference.

Comment: There is no difference. My problem comes from my project: I have created a new cn1 project in eclipse and copied the src files. It works now. I don't know what went wrong but in my new project there are some syntax I used that would not compile anymore. Tell my if you want me to provide more details. Thank you very much.

Comment: It might be an older build.xml or something like that in the old project